# mailgun configuration slight issue with TXT record

Tags: dns, whm, mailgun

I am attempting to set up mailgun on my server.

i am editing the DNS records through whm.

One record is causing me issues

```
"v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
```

I have set this to a TXT record - but if I don't add quotes around the record it gets changed to v=spf1.

However mailgun is not recognising this record. (it recognises another TXT record in double quotes though - however that one is not set as my domain name but rather `k1._domainkey`

Is there a way to enter this in WHM without the double quotes - or is it likely to be a problem elsewhere (and how do I check that it is correctly set?)

I am quite new to anything other than setting MX records so if more info is needed just let me know.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well wouldn't you know I just managed to sort it.

If anyone is having the same issue simply append a full stop (period for our american friends :-D) to the end of your domain name.

so `mydomain.com` becomes `mydomain.com.`

I had done this for other records by default as I just copied other entries but had missed it off this record.

Perhaps someone clever can tell me why the full-stop is required?

Comment: if your domain is example.com, and you put example.com IN TXT "v=spf1.." what youre actually doing is creating a TXT record for example.com.example.com.  ie, BIND is treating example.com as a subdomain of example.com. the '.' at the end signifies that it is a fully qualified domain name, and not a subdomain.